# Enable/Disable randomly generated Text & Radio Inputs with Checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a PHP do while loop for generating text, radio and checkbox input fields. The text and radio fields are disabled by default and I want to enable them as I check the corresponding checkbox. I have assigned random IDs and tried many jQuery solutions but I'm still having problems.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `test` ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = 0;
  do{
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if($row){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="txt form-control" name="txt" style="width:200px;" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" id="radio_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="rdo" name="rdo<?php echo $count; ?>" value="yes" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" id="radio_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="rdo" name="rdo<?php echo $count; ?>" value="no" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="check_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="checks" name="check" /></td>
    </tr>

<?php
    $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
while($row);
?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $('#check_<?php echo $count; ?>').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#txt_<?php echo $count; ?>').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#radio_<?php echo $count; ?>').prop('disabled', false);
        }else{
            $('#txt_<?php echo $count; ?>').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#radio_<?php echo $count; ?>').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**My solution:**

```
    $(function() {
      $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', false);
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    });
```

This Function Worked charms :)

Comment: Can you show your jquery code what you have tried so far ??

Comment: I have tried about 5 codes which work for single input fields but fail as I assign them random IDs

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change", ".checks", function () {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).parents("tr .txt").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).parents("tr .rdo").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
})
```

You can also write a single script for this using `class` attribute like above.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).close is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (0test.php:89)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.2.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-2.2.2.min.js:3)

Comment: Try this `$(this).parents("tr").find(".txt").removeAttr("disabled");`. Same with the below.

Comment: Thanks alot @SK Jajoriya :)

Comment: Thanks alot @SK Jajoriya :)

Answer (score 0):

This JQuery Function worked for me :)

```
$(function() {
      $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', false);
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    });
```